# display file instead of RSC version

Tags: c#

Whenever I try to open a custom file to a textbox or something which will display code. it never works, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.
I want my program to display what is inside the file when I open it, I have this below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Show Dialogue and get result
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "rbt files (*.rbt)|*.rbt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (myStream)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText("", CodeBox.Text);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("RBT7 file open");
            }
        }
    }
```

It only displays the RBT7 in a messagebox which is not what I want, I want the file to open and display its information to some sort of textbox which displays code.

Comment: What is a CodeBox?  And why don't you display the Message of the exception?  `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` Then people will be able to help you.

Comment: codebox (A textbox which displays code)

Comment: you have several problems. why are you trying to write to a file that you are wanting to open?

Comment: Please add the output of `ex.Message` to your question. This will tell people what error you are getting.

Comment: ex.Message gives me no errors, I just want to know how to display code from a file i'm opening to a textbox

Comment: If your code display the `MessageBox` in your `catch` block, then you do have an error.  Add the `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [documentation for File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx).

The first parameter:

*path*: The file to write to.

You're passing it `""`. That is not a path. Are you trying to write all the text from the file into `CodeBox.Text` or write all the text from `CodeBox.Text` into a file?

In your comment, you indicate the former. Try this:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"your file path");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    CodeBox.Text += line;
}
```

You haven't shown the code for `CodeBox` so I can't guarantee the results of this.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying write all text from the file into CodeBox.Text, but it has to use the resources/information I have for that specific file formar

Comment: @Fantaseb I noticed you've asked a few questions but haven't upvoted/downvoted/accepted any answers. You should accept the answer that best answers your question and toss and upvote their way.

Comment: tnw sorry was away for a moment, thanks that worked :) How do I give you points for your answer?

Comment: @Fantaseb You'll see up and down arrows next to every answer and question. Those are buttons for upvoting and downvoting. Also, since you are the OP, you can click the check mark next to an answer to mark it as the one that resolved your question.

Comment: need 15 rep to vote you up but I will remember when I get more rep

Comment: @Fantaseb Try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Replace this code

```
            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                using (myStream)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText("", CodeBox.Text);
                }
            }
```

with this

```
{
    CodeBox.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```